# Adding Raster to ImageServer: What are the Geodata Transformation Parameters?

Tags: arcgis-server, image-service, affine-transformation

I'm trying to add a raster image to an Image Service, via the [Add Raster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/rest/apiref/isadd.html) operation. My original image file is accompanied by a world file, containing the six parameters of an affine transformation. I want to use them in Add Raster's *Geodata Transforms* parameter to georeference my raster image.

[Esri's documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/rest/apiref/index.html?isgeodatatransforms.html) shows the following parameters for polynomial transformations (I want a first order transformation):

```
{
  "geodataTransform" : "Polynomial",
  "geodataTransformArguments" : {  
    "sourcePoints" : [<sourcePoint1>, <sourcePoint2>, <sourcePoint3> ...], 
    "targetPoints" : [<targetPoint1>, <targetPoint2>, <targetPoint3> ...], 
    "coeffx" : [<coeffx11>, <coeffx12>],
    "coeffy" : [<coeffy11>, <coeffy12>],
    "inverseCoeffx" : [<inverseCoeffx11>, <inverseCoeffx12>],
    "inverseCoeffy" : [<inverseCoeffy11>, <inverseCoeffy12>],
    "spatialReference": {<spatialReference1>},
    "polynomialOrder": <polynomialOrder1>
  }
}
```

However, I don't understand the parameters *coeffx*, *coeffy*, *inverseCoeffx* and *inverseCoeffy*. Why are there only four / eight, instead of six? Esri's examples only show how to use the ground control points.